# Android application doesn't run properly from the first try

Tags: android, android-volley

Okay, so far my MainActivity for this simple app looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView moviesListView;
ArrayList <Movie> moviesList;
MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moviesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.moviesListView);
    moviesList = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    runProgram();
    moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.movies_layout, moviesList);
    moviesListView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
}

private void runProgram() {

    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/" +
            "discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2016-02-01&primary_release_date.lte=2016-02-18" +
            "&api_key=...............................";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    getMovies(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}


private void getMovies(JSONObject response) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    String imageBaseURL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";
    try {
        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            Movie movie = new Movie(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("overview"),
                    imageBaseURL + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("poster_path")
                    + "?&api_key=6b54bd769063ac68b99fac57aa334eae");
            moviesList.add(movie);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

What I am trying to do here is request movies from TMDB, and display them in a ListView. But my problem is that the first time you run the app, it doesn't display anything, you would only see white screen.
Now, if you try running it again, it would display the movies in the ListView. But if you clear the cache of the application and try running it one more time, you would see the white screen again... . I am really confused of what is going on here.
I've tried debugging it, and it seems like it is getting the data really fast, so whatever is happening is happening after that.

Also, here is the code of my Adapter in case:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    ArrayList<Movie> moviesList;
    int adapterResource;
    Context adapterContext;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Movie> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        moviesList = objects;
        adapterResource = resource;
        adapterContext = context;
        layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(adapterResource, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.movieImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
            viewHolder.movieName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieName);
            viewHolder.movieOverview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieOverview);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.movieImage).execute(moviesList.get(position).getImageURL());
        viewHolder.movieName.setText(moviesList.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.movieOverview.setText(moviesList.get(position).getOverview());
        return convertView;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView movieImage;
        public TextView movieName;
        public TextView movieOverview;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your `getView()` is called, you would start a new DownloadTask. That is simply wrong because the same image may already be downloaded/in the process of being downloaded

Use Universal Image loader or Picasso :

Instead of this :

```
new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.movieImage).execute(moviesList.get(position).getImageURL());
```

Use :

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(moviesList.get(position).getImageURL())
   .into(viewHolder.movieImage);
```

Also, it seems that your `getMovies()` function is executed on main thread. Since you are parsing a JSON here, move it to background thread by using an `AsyncTask`

Thirdly, after you do `getMovies(response);`, you need to call `notifyDataSetChange()` on your `moviesAdapter`

Comment: Where should that code go exactly? and instead of what? Thank you, I will try it as soon as you let me know.

Comment: Awesome! It worked by adding the Picasso library and the moviesAdapter.notifyDataSetChange(). I will do some reading now about the multithreading in order to add it. Thank you for the help! I learned 3 new things at once.